# I can't parse string pointer to my function

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters, reference

My problem is I can't make my program to read `char *word` in function `read_word_details` and parse it back to `solve_task_1` function.

```
  void read_word_details(int *x, int *y, int *orientation, char *word) {
        char *p, input[20];
        fgets(input, 20, stdin);
        p = strtok(input, " ");
       *x = string_to_number(p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        *y = string_to_number(p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        *orientation = string_to_number(p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        word = p;
    }

    void solve_task_1() {
        char input[20], *p;
        fgets(input, 20, stdin);
        p = strtok(input, "a");
        int n = string_to_number(p);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            int x, y, orientation;
            char *word;
            read_word_details(&x, &y, &orientation, word);
            printf("%d %d %d %s\n", x, y, orientation, word);
        }
    }
```

My input is
`1`
`1 2 3 asd`,
and my output is `1 2 3 HH9u[]A\A]A^A_ff.`, instead of `1 2 3 asd`.

**Edit:** My `string_to_number` function is:

```
int string_to_number(char *p)
{
    int length = strlen(p);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (p[i] >= '0' && p[i] <= '9') {
        sum *= 10;
        sum += p[i] - '0';
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What is `string_to_number`?. [Edit] and show a [mcve]

Comment: Parameters act like local variables, so `word = p;` only has a local effect. Also, since `p` is pointing within a local array variable, it is no longer valid when the function returns. You could do `strcpy(word, p);` but the caller would need to provide the storage. Or you could change the parameter type to `char **word` and set `*word = malloc(strlen(p)+1);` `strcpy(*word, p);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott I tried and the result is Segmentation fault.

Comment: You probably never provided storage for `word`. In `solve_task_1`, if you change `char *word;` to `char word[20];` this should provide sufficient storage. Then the `strcpy` I mentioned in my earlier comment will work.

Comment: @IanAbbott, I tried this, and the result for `word` is a random string with 2 chars.